# How I can build and print to browser category tree?

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm, go

So I want to build a category script for products.

How I can build the category tree?

I have a DB like this...

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    cat_id integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    cat_name CHAR(24) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    cat_position tinyint NOT NULL,
    icon TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    keywords text NOT NULL, //for search
    active boolean NULL DEFAULT true,
    cat_description CHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

But I can't understand how it works because 1 product may be found in many categories...

I am coding on **GoLang**

Now I do like this...

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT cat_id, parent_id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE active = true ORDER BY Parent_id ASC")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()
```

Then I put rows into template...

```
{{range .}}
<p><a href="/show?getinfo={{ .Cat_id}}">{{ .Cat_id}}</a> - {{ .Parent_id}} - {{ .Cat_name}} <a href="/show?getinfo={{ .Cat_id}}">Показать</a>
{{end}}
```

In the end I would like to get something [similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHqoI.gif)

Comment: Why don´t you make an API who send datas from your DB and retrieve it with a "Front" language (HTML/JS/PHP...) to print them ?

Comment: because Golang can do similar tasks without an API.

If there are no other options, then JS